# Source code of current file in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to load source code of current file as String in Groovy (the file that defined the method currently running). How can I do it?

Most of answers I found were related to getting parent directory of current file or getting source of Groovy script. But my code is not a script, it is just a class.

Comment: What do you mean by "current file"? The file that defined the method currently running?

Comment: class file has not (human readable) source. Maybe try catch problem at higher level, overrinde GroovyClassLoader or GroovyShell GroovyScriptEngine http://www.groovy-lang.org/integrating.html

Comment: @ErnestKiwele yes, the file that defined the method currently running

Comment: are You familiar with `new Exception()` without `throw`, and few other technics to get StackTrace on live program?

Comment: @JacekCz I'm not interested in class file, I need source code. I don't want to override any shell or script engines, because this is Spock test. In this test I need to get the source code of the test to verify that all necessary assertions are made.

Comment: @JacekCz yes, I'm aware, but I'm looking for simple one-liner to do that as this is Groovy :)

Comment: I don't think you'll get a reliable way. Try checking the upstream stack frames: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getFileName()`

Comment: "In this test I need to get the source code of the test to verify that all necessary assertions are made." - are you trying to test a unit test? Isn't this an example of over-complicating test design?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Yes, I can change design of my test to achieve the same goal. Right now test data inside each particular test for readability, but I can externalize it and have one test that makes assertions with this data and another test that verifies if the test data is correct.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solution if you think it answers your question so others know it's answered, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know of a "simple one-liner to do that as this is Groovy" (your comment), it is possible to do this using an AST transformation.

The simplest way would be a local AST transformation using an Annotation. You annotate your test class. Then you have different options to retrieve the source code at run time. I would add it as value of a new Annotation which you could then get via reflection.

**Project**

I created a show-case repository on [github](https://github.com/MeneDev/groovy-get-source).

You should be able to use it directly via gradle / maven:

```
repositories {
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.MeneDev:groovy-get-source:96746d39f3'
}
```

Usage:

```
@SaveSource
class AClass {

    def getCode() {
        SourceCode sourceCode = this.class.getAnnotation(SourceCode)
        return sourceCode.value()
    }
}
```

**Required steps**

Annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Target([ElementType.TYPE])
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes = [SaveSourceASTTransformation])
public @interface SaveSource {

}
```

Transformation:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ASTNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstantExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformation

@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class SaveSourceASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
        if (nodes.length < 2) {
            return
        }
        if (!(nodes[0] instanceof AnnotationNode)) {
            return
        }
        if (!(nodes[1] instanceof ClassNode)) {
            return
        }
        def classNode = nodes[1] as ClassNode

        def annotationNode = new AnnotationNode(new ClassNode(SourceCode))
        def sourceCode = sourceUnit.source.reader.text
        annotationNode.addMember("value", new ConstantExpression(sourceCode))
        classNode.addAnnotation(annotationNode)
    }
}
```

Annotation for storing the source code (note the `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` so you can read the value at runtime):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface SourceCode {
    String value()
}
```